# How to include a field in API without adding the key/val in database?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, graphql, strapi

I am looking for a way the Strapi API returns a key/value pair which is calculate and added to the server response but not fetched from the Database:

I have done something like that using `ApolloServer` with `Prisma`. If you are wondering how I have done? then here is my setup:

> Note: I am not looking for how `slug` feature in Strapi but in general I like to know how dynamic/calculate fields can be added to Strapi API Server response.

file: `./src/resolvers/Team.js`

```
const Team = {
  slug(parent) {
    return parent.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  },
};

export { Team as default };
```

file: `./src/resolvers/index.js`

```
import { extractFragmentReplacements } from 'prisma-binding';
import Query from './Query';
import Mutation from './Mutation';
import Team from './Team';

const resolvers = {
  Query,
  Mutation,

  // static
  Team,
};

const fragmentReplacements = extractFragmentReplacements(resolvers);
export { resolvers, fragmentReplacements };
```

file: `./src/prisma.js`

```
import { Prisma } from 'prisma-binding';
import { fragmentReplacements } from './resolvers/index';

require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });

const prisma = new Prisma({
  typeDefs: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql',
  endpoint: process.env.API_URL,
  secret: process.env.PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET,
  fragmentReplacements,
});

export { prisma as default };
```

file: `./src/schema.graphql`

```
type Team {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  color: String!
  slug: String! // this is not in Db but taken care by `./src/resolvers/StaticTeam.js`
}
```

As you can see above that how I get the `slug` though that's not in database. I just like to have calculated `key:val` added to my API.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired functionality? ie Endpoint path/name with params sent and result

Comment: @ghosh, it's all experimental and I do not have any endpoint but this is what I need:
`{ id: 1, title: 'My Title', color: '#fff', slug: 'my-title' // this is not in Db but sever should send data in response }`

Comment: @ghosh as you suggested I joined the Slack Group but did not get any response yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I like to know how dynamic/calculate fields can be added to Strapi API Server response

Basically you are looking for a [Custom data response](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/custom-data-response.html#custom-data-response), most likely combined with a custom endpoint(since you don't want to override an existing endpoint).

You can do this by extending the existing API, lets break it down:

1. Add a custom API endpoint
   a. Add routing
   b. Add handler
   c. [Add permissions](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#manage-role-permissions)
2. Run some logic
3. Return a custom response

(1) To add a custom API endpoint to a user defined content type, you need to (a) add routing in the following directory:

```
./api/{content-type}/config/routes.json
```

Like so (in routes array):

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/teams/customData",
  "handler": "team.findCustomHandler",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
```

(b)add a method in the following directory:

```
./api/{content-type}/controllers/{Content-Type}.js
```

Like so:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    async findCustomHandler(ctx) {
      //your logic here
    }
};
```

You can use the original [find](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers) method to start off and add your values using your logic ([this is a great example](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/custom-data-response.html#apply-our-changes)):

```
  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.team.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.team.find(ctx.query);
    }
    // TODO: add your extra calculated value
    return entities.map(entity => {
    // You can do this here
    sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.restaurant }));
    }
  }
```

Docs you can check out:
[Extending a Model Controller](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/controllers.html#extending-a-model-controller)

Questions welcome